# How should I use scanf to get only one character from input?

Tags: c, char, scanf

I've solved a problem with pressing 'enter' before char but there is one more thing. Here is my code from Visual Studio:

```
 #include <stdio.h>



int main() {
    char ch, yn;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    printf("You entered -> %c\n", ch);
    printf("Continue? [y/n]: ");
    scanf(" %c", &yn);
    if (yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y') {
        while (ch != 'q' && ch != 'Q') {
            printf("---------------------------------\n");
            printf("Enter another character ([q]uit): ");
            scanf(" %c", &ch);
            printf("You entered -> %c\n", ch);
        }
    }
    else if (yn == 'n' || yn == 'N') {
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n-- Invalid character! --\a\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So if the user enters something like '**abc**' instead of '**a**' then '**b**' is for '**Continue?**' question. And error message in code appears. That's my problem, what should I write to read only first char?

Comment: Rule 1 for reading single characters with `scanf`: don't do it. Rule 2 for reading single characters with `scanf`: don't use `getchar`, either. Rule 3 for reading single characters with `scanf`: if you simply must do it, use `" %c"`, with a leading space.  So it looks like you followed all the rules, so we either have go back to rule 1, or we have to go on to...

Comment: ...Rule 4 about `scanf`: Don't use it. Rule 5 about `scanf`: If you're just learning C, it might be okay to use `scanf` for the first week or two, for really simple stuff. Rule 6 about `scanf`: If you're trying to do something at all tricky with `scanf`, and it's not working, don't waste time on it, just live without doing the thing.  Rule 7 about `scanf` If you're trying to do something tricky, and it's not working, but you really want to do the thing, it's time to learn how to do input using better techniques, that is, not using `scanf`.

Comment: Finally, it appears that what you're trying to do here fits my definition of "something at all tricky".  Does your program work if the user types the proper input?  If so, great, you're done. Is your question about how to make the program behave more reasonably if the user types incorrect input?  That's a worthy goal -- human factors and the user experience are important topics -- **but**, you will *never be able to handle incorrect input gracefully using `scanf`*, so please, don't bother.